# indent with 'tab' button in python commandline

Tags: python, indentation, prompt

hi everyone :)
my problem is, up until now, i have exclusively used tabs to indent python, as i find it easier than spaces, but for no reason i know, python interactive prompt, the basic python.exe one, suddenly refuses to accept the tab button, all it does is flash the cursor. all i can think of is that my computer in suddenly treading the window like any other, using tab to cycle input things, in this case the single one. also, before now, i could use the up button to reach previously typed code, the if i submit that line with no changes, use the down button to access the line that came after it, but now up works, but as if i had changed the line, eg moves me back to the "bottom" of the list of inputs, so down doesn't work.... my question simply is: how do i get my good old tab and down button to work like i want them to again? :(
thanks xxx

Comment: Do not use tabs to indent Python code. A reasonable editor will make indenting with spaces much easier than tabs. Seriously, don't ever use tabs.

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm using Ubuntu linux and my tab is working fine ). Also, there is a python [recommendation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use spaces instead of tabs. See Code lay-out section.

Comment: @ikostia he's using Windows, I guess, and that's why his CLI is weird (cmd.exe is terrible)

Comment: dont dis tabs. i like them. int the interactive prompt, i want a easily visible intent that takes one button press. voila, tab.

Comment: @James if you use ipython or bpython then indentation is taken care of for you. Tabs are like smoking: you might enjoy it but they're harmful to you and everyone around you.

Comment: i seriously want to grab razor blades when i see IPython. I personally hate it. not saying it is bad, just dont like it. also, could we pretty please hunt an actual answer? rather than "OMG TAB FAILS" id be verrrrry happy if we could xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, i would like a real answer. that is why i posted this question. if you havent noticed, i am acknowledging all answers but politely trying to steer this back to my real question. ta.

Comment: also, "bpython is a fancy interface to the Python interpreter for Unix-like operating systems (I hear it works fine on OS X)" and you yourself just said im using windows, rafe kettler

Comment: I am able to use tabs just fine in the Python console (started via python.exe) on Windows (cmd.exe has nothing to do with it @Rafe).

Comment: i was able to too until very very reciently .....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows with the standard cmd.exe console (and it would have been helpful for you to have stated this up front) then you can use the TAB and arrow keys exactly as you desire.

Comment: i am using cmd.exe, which is why im confused as to why what i said in my question is happening... thanks anyway xxx

Comment: @James It just works. Not sure what your problem is. Something messed up. Hard to tell from here.

Answer (score 0):

I recently observed this behavior too, on Windows, using cmd.exe. It also happens with Console2 - an alternate shell I sometimes use.

Though I do always use spaces in normal code in an editor, I had been accustomed to using the Tab key to indent in short multi-line inputs in the interactive python.exe interpreter. Recently that stopped working - pressing the Tab key flashes the cursor and doesn't indent. Using spaces does work fine here, though it's not as convenient past a couple of indentations.

I suspect (but am not certain) that the cause was installation of pyreadline or rlcompleter - I had been messing with trying to get tab completion in an interpreter in an embedded application on Windows. Of course in your case another installation could have included those packages.